# Where do we add package.json file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I'm new to tests, especially with JavaScript.

When I write tests in .NET, I create a new project and have all my tests in there. However, it's time to test the JavaScript.

I'm trying to achieve this using Karma and Jasmine. I'm following a [tutorial](http://jdav.is/2016/02/01/karma-jasmine-visual-studio-including-visual-studio-code/). It states

`You’ll simply need to right-click on your project and add the NPM Configuration File which creates a package.json file in your project’s main folder.`

Does this mean I want my tests to be part of my main UI project? I also don't know what it means by my project's main folder...

Comment: run `npm init` in your main project folder - usually where your src resides

Comment: @AdamWolski, does this mean usually your test units also live in the main project

Comment: @MyDaftQestions correct, unit tests lay along with source code in the same project. They dont have to (e2e tests), but in most cases it is desired

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample directory structure of a generic  application

```
myprojectDir/<all configuration files> // such as package.json Readme.MD
myprojectDir/node_modules/<all npm dependencies> // these will be installed using npm install command
myprojectDir/app/<you application folder>
```

You need to initiate a project using npm init command. Here myprojectDir is your main project folder